# Solve for rational roots of $f(x)=x^4-5x^3+11x^2-16x+12$

Tags: polynomials

Solve for the rational roots of

$$\begin{align*}f(x)=x^4-5x^3+11x^2-16x+12\tag{1}\end{align*}$$

I know the rational roots are factors of 12, so just try $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 12$ one by one?

Bad thing is try many times, I've tried $1$, and $-1$ and $2$ is.(Is any rules in trying? $1$ first or $-1$ first, or $2$ first?)

Lucky thing is $2$ is one root, and multiplicity of $x-2$ is $2$.

So by method of undetermined coefficients, we can get the factor.

$$\begin{align*}x^2-x+3\tag{2}\end{align*}$$

Shoud I show $(2)$ is irreducible over $Q$, and how? calculate values when $x$ takes over $\pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 12$?

Comment: It is irreducible, no rational roots. Use the Quadratic Formula. Or try the only candidates for roots $\pm 1$, $\pm 3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why there is no need to check 4,6,12? If I use Quadratic Formula, then it is something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462706/check-the-proof-ofx21-is-irreducible-over-q)

Comment: You have arrived at $x^2-x+3$, and want to find out whether it is irreducible. Like any quadratic or cubic, it is irreducible iff it has no rational root. And any rational root of $x^2-x+3$ must divide the constant term of **this** polynomial, so it must divide $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The next step is indeed to show that $x^2 - x + 3$ is irreducible over the rationals; but you don't need to look at that whole list of possible roots.  You just need to look at what the rational root theorem tells you about this new, smaller polynomial: so you only need to check $1, -1, 3, -3$.

Comment: Why there is no need to check 4,6,12?